# Disable Secure Boot to install Windows 8.1 in UEFI mode via USB stick

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, uefi

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 using a USB stick from UEFI mode. I used [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to format the USB stick as "GPT for UEFI".

The problem is that my PC can boot in UEFI mode only if I turn Secure Boot off. Secure boot in the BIOS is enabled and grayed out. Is there a way to boot from the USB stick in UEFI mode when Secure Boot is enabled?  Alternately, is there a way to disable secure boot?

PC: [Acer Aspire E3-112](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_Aspire#List_of_Acer_Aspire_Laptop_Models[2])

Comment: What is the make/model of the computer?

Comment: Its an Acer e3 112

Comment: Secure Boot can be disabled by first [setting the Supervisor Password in the BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285841/disabled-secure-boot-and-enabled-uefi-for-dual-boot-on-acer/1001155#1001155) (after that the setting is no longer greyed out in menu *Boot*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody encountered the problem that the USB stick doesn't boot in UEFI mode you need to format the USB stick as FAT32 instead of NTFS. It will boot then in UEFI even if Secure boot is enabled, at least using [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/).

For the second problem namely how to disable secure boot when it's grayed out I haven't configured yet a solution for that.

Comment: If its grayed out you cannot change the manufacturers enforcement of secure boot in the bios, :-(

Comment: @Moab: [Yes, you can](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285841/disabled-secure-boot-and-enabled-uefi-for-dual-boot-on-acer/1001155#1001155)!

Answer (score -2):

Use universal iso creator and just create a bootable ISO. All laptops will accept this interface for boot and install.

Here is a link to the product- http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

The distro you need to select is windows 8.1 then select the iso then the drive you would like to use.

I have personally down 1000s of installs of windows 8.1 with this product without any issues.

Comment: Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software in an answer.

Comment: Rufus is a similar program.  The question doesn't ask for a different program to accomplish the result, it asks how to solve a specific problem with secure boot.  Can you address that in your answer?  BTW, I didn't downvote your answer, but that is the likely reason.

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft offers a free Windows media creation tool that does that.  If your secure boot setting is greyed out, this may be your best bet.

From [this Windows site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media), you can download a Windows 8.1 iso directly to a USB flash drive. That one works. I have used it.

Click the `Create Media` button downloads `mediacreationtool.exe`.  Use that to prepare the flash drive.

Comment: Can you please include all relevant information in the answer and not simply have a link.  Microsoft has a history of moving links and old links are not setup to be redirected resulting in dead links in the future

Comment: All there is to it is a Microsoft download link with which you can automatically create the installation/repair flash drive. Can you please tell me what other 'relevant information' You would like. Look at the link and you will see.

Comment: The user isn't asking how to make USB install media.  He's already done that.  He just wants to know how to disable Secure Boot on his computer.

Comment: He also asks: "  Is there any way to boot from the USB stick in UEFI mode when Secure Boot is enabled?" - and that's what he gets if he creates the flash drive from the link I posted. If his secure boot setting is greyed out, that is his best bet.

Comment: I have tried out the Microsoft tool but the usb stick would boot in mbr mod not in uefi